# Two first elements from array and join them

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a following array

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "2.16.1.0",
      "2.16.1.255",
      "256"
    ],
    [
      "2.16.3.0",
      "2.16.3.255",
      "256"
    ],
    [
      "2.16.6.0",
      "2.16.7.255",
      "512"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the following output of it:

```
2.16.1.0-2.16.1.255
2.16.3.0-2.16.3.255
2.16.6.0-2.16.7.255
```

so far I have succeeded in outputting the first two required values

```
cat ./data.txt | jq -r '.[][]|nth(0,1)'

2.16.1.0
2.16.1.255
2.16.3.0
2.16.3.255
2.16.6.0
2.16.7.255
```

but how do I merge/join them? Not sure I'm going in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

String interpolation can work here too:

```
jq -r '.data[] | "\(.[0])-\(.[1])"'
```

Or string concatenation:

```
jq -r '.data[] | .[0] + "-" + .[1]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select the first 2 items in the array (`.[0:2]`) and then [`join()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#join) that with a `-`.

If you need the `2` items dynamic, you could use `.[:-1]` to just *remove* the last index. More about the `.[x:y]` slice can be found in the [Array string slice documentation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-string-slice).

---

```
.data[] | .[0:2] | join("-")
```

```
.data[] | .[:-1] | join("-")
```

Both give:

```
2.16.1.0-2.16.1.255
2.16.3.0-2.16.3.255
2.16.6.0-2.16.7.255
```

---

###### [Online JQ Play Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0LaVqPz4--l)

Comment: That seems to be the easiest and correct way to do it.  I started using nth for some reason, it wasn't quite right.

Comment: @KarlsD Not particularly useful here, but to show you `nth/1` and `nth/2` in action, this also produces your desired results: `.data[] | [nth(0,1)] | join("-")` and `.data[] | [nth(0,1; .[])] | join("-")`